# 'Invalid field recordtype.developername for Case' error while fetching recordtype.developer name

Tags: apex

Below is the code snippet:

```
list<case> clist=[select id,recordtypeId,recordtype.developername from case limit 2];
for(case cs:clist){
    newcase__c bInstance = new newcase__c(); 
    Map<String,newcase_Config__mdt> Mapmetadata = newcase_Config__mdt.getAll();
    for(String mdtMap : Mapmetadata.keySet()){
        String fromField = Mapmetadata.get(mdtMap).From__c; //assume the value is recordtype.developername
        String toField = Mapmetadata.get(mdtMap).to__c; //assume the value is recordtype.developername
        system.debug('@@'+cs.recordtype.developername);
        bInstance.put(toField,cs.get(fromField));    
        system.debug('binstance'+binstance);        
    }
}
```

Here, `from__c` is holding the recordtype.developername on the case object and `to__c` is holding the `recordtype.developername` on the `newcase__c` object. In line 9, the fetched recordtype value has to get assigned to newcase__c's recordtype.developername. But I am getting an error as '`Invalid field recordtype.developername for Case`'. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing here is related to the fact that the Case record actually only contains the RecordTypeId, not the Developer Name as well (as that's on the related Record Type entry).

There are a couple of ways that you could get around this:

1. Construct a Map of the Record Type Ids to Developer Names before you enter the for loop and retrieve the appropriate Developer Name based on the RecordTypeId value on the Case.
2. Use the getRecordTypeInfosByID method of the DescribeSObjectResult class to retrieve the Developer Name on the fly based on the RecordTypeId of the Case.This is cleaner in your code, but not as efficient if you are running the code for large collections of Cases.

These might help:

'https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeSObjectResult_getRecordTypeInfosByID

https://salesforcescool.blogspot.com/2021/05/dynamically-get-record-type-of.html